# Can't negotiate handshake from Angular to Azure SignalR (.NET CORE host)

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to change from local SignalR service on .NET CORE 2.1 back-end to Azure SignalR.

All: Angular (@aspnet/signalr), SignalR and Azure SignalR packages in v1.0.4.

At local configuration everything works great.

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials());               
        });


services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    //options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    //options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});


services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});
```

and

```cs
app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<SomeHub>("/ws/somehub");
});
```

after changes:

```cs
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(Configuration["AzureSignalRConnectionString"]);

app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
{
     routes.MapHub<SomeHub>("/ws/somehub");
});
```

What I revice during negotiation is:

204 after OPTIONS

404 after POST

The URL is correct, starts with HTTPS and ends with 'ws/somehub/negotiate'

Answer (score 0):

First of all Comment your `CORSPolicy` related code from `Startup.cs`  and Try it

Add code in your `Startup.cs`

For `Configure` method

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
```

Comment: Still the same. Do You really think it's backend's fault, not Azure Service?

Comment: May be yes it's Azure App service's fault if  You add **CORS  Policy**  in `startup.cs` then  don't need  to set **CORS policy** into **Azure Portal**.